# Regex backreference to be equal for inputs: 'UserProfile' and 'user-profile'

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio

I'm using [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/) to group my tabs in Visual Studio. I'm having difficulties finding the correct regular expression to group my tabs using the conventions I've used.

It works using two named backreferences. It groups tabs that have a matching `<Name>` and allows you to select the different `<Ext>`. The problem is, here are the files I'd like to be grouped:

- UserProfileController.cs
- UserProfileViewModel.cs
- UserProfile.cshtml
- user-profile.js
- user-profile.less

So far, I've got an expression that matches the first 3 and last 2 into two separate groups.

```
(?<Name>(.*[/\\])?.+?)(?<Ext>(ViewModel|Controller)?\..+)
```

The problem is manipulating the output of the backreference. The comparison is case-insensitive anyway, so all I really need to do is remove the `-` from the backreference output. Is this possible?

*Note: I've put this on StackOverflow as, at its heart, it's a RegEx question, though its purpose for me is very specific. I'm not too confident about this, so please let me know if you think this belongs somewhere else.*

Comment: It's not a normal "programming" question, but at its core I'd say it's very similar to most other regular expression questions I've seen that are accepted.

Comment: Indeed. Infact my [tag:c#] tag is probably not necessary now I think about it. Hmm tricky one.. Whereelse could it belong though?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just tagging it "regex", in my mind. Or replace `C#` with maybe a visual-studio tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed TabsStudio's support asking if there was a way I could do this within the addon. To my surprise, after a couple of emails, they implemented this feature! It is possible as of **v3.1.5**, released **28 Oct 2013**.

The new feature allows multiple capture groups with the same name to be concatenated into one string.

### My Expression:

```
(?<Path>(.*[/\\])*)(?<Ext>_?)(?<Name>.+)(?<Ext>\.cshtml)|(?<Name>.+?)(?<Ext>(ViewModel|Model|Controller|Helper|Utilities)?\.cs)|(?<Ext>_?)((?<Name>.+)-)*(?<Name>.*)(?<Ext>(\.min)?\.(js|less|css))|(?<Name>(.*[/\\])?.+?)(?<Ext>\..+)
```

### Explanation:

1. `(?<Path>(.*[/\\])*)(?<Ext>_?)(?<Name>.+)(?<Ext>\.cshtml)|`

   - _UserProfile.cshtml
   - UserProfile.cshtml

     Matches my Razor views. I prefix my partial views and layouts with an underscore. I omit the path here because I tend not to call my views `Index.cshtml` as I've always thought it was ambiguous.
2. `(?<Name>.+?)(?<Ext>(ViewModel|Model|Controller|Helper|Utilities)?\.cs)|`

   - UserProfileController.cs
   - UserProfileViewModel.cs
   - UserProfileUtilities.cs

     Matches various suffixes of C# code files. This could of course be extended to include others, such as `Wrapper`, `Extensions`, `Factory`, etc.
3. `(?<Ext>_?)((?<Name>.+)-)*(?<Name>.*)(?<Ext>(\.min)?\.(js|less|css))|`

   - user-profile.js
   - user-profile.min.css
   - _user-profile.less

     Matches styles and scripts. The underscore is prepended to the extension because I use it to prefix any `.less` files that are never requested directly (such as `_mixins.less`).
4. `(?<Name>(.*[/\\])?.+?)(?<Ext>\..+)`

   - UserProfile.resx

     A general fallback regex. This is the default in TabsStudio.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about tab studio, I only know about RegEx

If there is always only one "-" in the file name
You can separate the file name in two parts.

The regex will be like this

```
(?<Name1>([^-]*[/\\])?[^-]+?)-?(?<Name2>[^-]+?)(?<Ext>(ViewModel|Controller)?\..+)
```

to remove the "-" in the file name, your back ref will look like this:

```
${Name1}${Name2}${Ext}
```

Comment: The files aren't that likely to have more than one hyphen, but it is possible. As it happens, I only have one .less and one .js file that contains more than one hyphen.

Either way, your approach wouldn't work with TabsStudio as the group names must be `<Name>` and `<Ext>`.